# Unsure how to connect an api using nodejs

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I'm trying to connect the openai api into my app but I'm not sure why it's not working. From my frontend, I have a `createUserData` that receives an input and then stores it to my MongoDB database. But now, I want to send that input that I received to the openai API and get a response based on what they said. I tried implementing it here but it crashed on me with this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\server\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\server\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\server\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17844) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise 
rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:17844) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

For some reason I crash when I try and call this API, am I doing it wrong?

Right now I just want to log whatever the response I get from the API, once I'm able to do that then I will store it to the database as well. But I can't even log it as I get an error. Here is my  code:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
// create new user data
const createUserData = async (req, res) => {
    const {id, scores, transcript} = req.body
    const user_id = req.user._id
    console.log(user_id)

    

    const configuration = new Configuration({
        apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-002",
        prompt: "Provide personal feedback for me and give me tips: " + transcript,
        temperature: 0.7,
        max_tokens: 256,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0,
    });

    console.log(response)
    const newUserData = new UserData({
        id: id,
        scores: scores,
        transcript: transcript,
        user_id: user_id
    })

    // add doc to db
    try {
        await newUserData.save()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }

    console.log('POST:', newUserData)
    return res.status(201).json({user_data: newUserData})
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct API key in the `OPENAI_API_KEY` environment variable?

Comment: Yes, now I changed it from `process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY` to putting my key there and it worked. But doing this, I still can't get any response from the API. Like the request gets sent but I just get `[ [Object] ]` as a response. Do you know why?

Comment: Could you try it again when you changed the res to new clear json like **res.status(200).json({test:'test'})**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, in my old code I made a separate function for it but now I have everything in just one function, is that why it's not working? I am already using `res.status(201)` to return the new user data object that was created and stored in the DB to the frontend